# Разряд прилагательных

Tags: морфология, прилагательные

К какому разряду, на ваш взгляд, относятся прилагательные в следующих словосочетаниях: **волчья стая, заячий след, заячий выводок**?

Вопрос, должен сказать, спорный, т. к. разные учебники относят их к разным разрядам: одни относят их к притяжательным, другие — к относительным, третьи — к относительно-притяжательным.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Волчья стая, заячий след, заячий выводок -  я бы все эти прилагательные отнесла к притяжательным. Все перечисленные прилагательные на -ий, -ья,-ье( с суфф.-j-) и на -иный (куриный, утиный) обозначают общую родовую принадлежность, а не принадлежность одному лицу или животному. Это свойство, присущее тому или иному живому существу, эта особенность и вызывает сомнение, позволяет легко переходить в разряд относительных: волчья шапка (из волка), заячий полушубок (из зайца), в качественные: волчий аппетит, заячья натура (трусливая).

Когда-то моя учительница нас учила: если прилагательное можно заменить без изменения смысла на местоимения мой, твой, наш, это притяжательное прилагательное. Моя стая - если я волк, то это моя, **наша стая - чья? волчья - притяжательное.** По смыслу получается как "моя компания", "мои друзья".

Заячий след - оставленный зайцем; мой след, наш след, след, оставленный мной, принадлежит мне. Чей? заячий след - притяжательное, хотя оттенок относительности есть.

Общее лексическое значение относительного прилагательного - "относящийся к данному предмету, характерный для данного предмета". След - от зайца, он не относится к зайцу, не похож на него, не из него сделан, он непосредственно им оставлен, значит, **ему принадлежит**.

Заячий выводок - не сделан из зайцев, а сами зайцы и есть выводок, можно заменить "заячьи дети" - **чьи?-притяжательное.**

Comment: Мне понравился ваш ответ. Я тоже так думаю. Но вы пишете: " Заячий след - оставленный зайцем". Но в Интернете в учебниках именно в значении это словосочетание относят к  к относительному прилагательному.

Comment: Не думаю, хотя я уже сказала, что оттенок относительности есть - можно вывести свойство следа через отношение к зайцу, но ведь само отношение  тоже притяжательное: след принадлежит зайцу, значит чей? Можно сравнить с переносным значением слова след: он оставил свой след в науке, а вот и прямое значение: мои следы на песке. Чей? мой, свой - всё равно притяжательность перетягивает.

Comment: @ Людмила,с вами полностью согласна   Грамма.ру.

Answer (score 1):

**Волчья стая** — стая, состоящая  из волков. Относительное прилагательное. Нет значения принадлежности.

**Заячий след** — принадлежит единичной особи. Притяжательное прилагательное (обозначает принадлежность).

Характерные особенности **заячьих следов.** Относительно-притяжательное прилагательное (обозначает свойственность данного вида).

**Заячий выводок** — принадлежит единичной особи. Притяжательное прилагательное.

Comment: Волчья стая - в учебниках говорится, что общеродовая  принадлежность. Кстати, Грамота.ру тоже относит это прилагательное к притяжательному.

Comment: Странно,  здесь даже вопрос "чья"  не подходит,  скорее стая "какая". И разве можно сказать: стая принадлежит волкам?

Comment: https://studfiles.net/preview/3277641/page:19/  Прочитайте, здесь эти прилагательные относят к притяжательным. Есть и другие источники, которые относят эти прилагательные к относительным.

Comment: Да, я посмотрела. Но мне кажется, что различать прилагательные нужно преимущественно по семантическому принципу (а не по суффиксам), учитывая, что прилагательные свободно могут перемещаться по разрядам, сохраняя свою форму. Дали бы четкое смысловое ОПРЕДЕЛЕНИЕ, и не было бы сложных проблем. Мы почему-то любим из простого делать сложное.

Comment: Да, конечно, вы правы. Но там ведь не формальный признак, а семантический.

Comment: По семантике притяжательное прилагательное должно иметь значение принадлежности, но волчья стая не принадлежит ни отдельному волку, не всем волкам.  Сравним: группа экспертов - экспертная группа, это относительное прилагательное.